# setInterval runs only once if assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I develop vue 2 application and I need to run setInterval for the few times and stop it after some time.
This works fine

```
setInterval(() => {
        console.log('function do this')
      }, 2000)
```

bit this doesn't work as expected. actually it doesn't runs even once.

```
const refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('function do this')
      }, 2000)

/* later */
setTimeout(clearInterval(refreshIntervalId), 10000)
```

How can I start setInterval?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(clearInterval(refreshIntervalId), 10000)
```

This is running immediately. You need to wrap `clearInterval` in a function to prevent the interval from being cancelled.

```
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(refreshIntervalId), 10000)
```